# Finding Null and Alternative Hypothesis

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

Edit: Was able to figure out question by myself.

I am struggling mostly with part a, but also part b.  I think because of the way the question is worded, I am having  a hard time finding the null and alternative hypothesis.

a. For part a, I was thinking that the null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis would be:
H0: u=10  (n)
HA: u<10  (n)

or I was thinking it would be:
H0: u=5 (n/2)
HA: u>5 (n/2)

I honestly am not sure what the null and alternative hypothesis are because of the wording of the question.  Also I'm not sure what it means to find 'the test with significance level 0.1'.  Does this mean to find a test statistic? If so, how would I do this for this question (not sure)

b.  For part b, type II error is when you fail to reject the null when the alternative is true.
So for this case would I use a binomial probability so that we are not in the rejection region and so that p=0.75.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to get you started--without a thorough discussion of (b), (c), and (d).

(1) The random variable $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=10, p)$ counts the
magician's successes in ten trials. If he has no ability and is strictly guessing then $p = 1/2.$ So let $H_0: p = 1/2.$ Then then it seems from the wording
in the rest of the parts that the alternative should be $H_a: p > 1/2.$

A good estimate of $p$ is $\hat p = X/n.$ If the magician gets a 'relatively
large' number correct, then we should reject $H_0$ and admit he has some
ability to call the result by listening to the sound. The question is
where to draw the line. The significance level is based on the 'null
distribution' $\mathsf{Binom}(n=10, 1/2).$ Given that the magician
has no ability, you want to be fooled into believing him only rarely.
So you will want him to be right "much" of the time. For the significance
level $\alpha = .1,$ you want to find $k$ (called the 'critical value') such that $P(X \ge k\, |\, p = 1/2) \le .1.$ For example, 
$P(X \ge 9\,|\,p=1/2) =  0.0107.$ So it seems you can select a smaller $k$
and still get a significance level 0.1. Maybe try $k=8.$ Use the formula for the binomial
PDF to find what critical value to use.

(2) Here you want to know the chance you will accept  $H_0$ (call him a liar)
when he really can call the right answer with probability $p = 0.75.$ You
will use the same critical value as in (1).

I have given you some help formulating the null and alternative hypotheses.
I hope that is a start, you have more work to do.

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  I will go try the problem now with the information provided.  Is it okay, if I do the problem and ask you later if my work is correct?  Thanks so much.

Comment: Also, in the problem, what does it mean find the test, with significance level 0.1.  I'm not sure what find the test means, or what it is asking for.

Comment: Please edit your progress into the Question, so everyone can see it. I may not be available for a couple of days, but there are many others on the site who might be of help once you show some progress. // Finding the test boils down to finding the critical value.: Saying when to Reject and when not to.

Comment: Great sounds good.

Comment: Hello, I managed to do parts A-C pretty well after the hints you provided.  Now I am not so sure how to do part C.  We want alpha to be less than or equal to 0.1 and 1-type II error to be greater than or equal to 0.9.  We are asked to calculate n.  I'm not sure the process for doing this.  Thanks.

Comment: I got n=23 but I' not sure if this is right